# Integrating Google Authentication in Existing Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, google-oauth

We have an application designed 3 years back in ASP.Net & SQL Server 2008.

We designed our own login DB design and forms authentication for the application with the help of ApplicationUser, Role, Then other transaction tables using UserId for getting the corresponding user records, history records.

So far no issues with new user registration and bringing and managing existing user records.

`Now our client wants to integrate, Google Account Login for the new customer 
and even the existing customer can sign in with the Google account.`

We are wondering how it is possible. If you use Google Account to login, how we manage UserId mapping and other tables.

**Is it possible to integrate the Google Account Login with the existing Application has designed with its own login implementation?**

If yes, what are the things to be followed/considered for implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291066(v=vs.110).aspx). It uses claims based authentication so all a user needs to access your site is a security token with a claim. You could set up a separate Security Token Service that authenticates users based on your own database and users could also retrieve tokens by logging in through Google or with any other party you configure your app to trust.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion might be to use the nuget package [SimpleAuthentication](https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication).**

Out of the box, it has an MVC controller which means all you need to do is implement the code for checking if the user exists in your system, etc. (ie. when you come back to your website from Google).

If you're on webforms (appologies) then you need to do a bit more work by creating your own form call back and then handling the return from Google.

** Disclosure: I'm one of the 2 main contributors for it.

Comment: It looks really good. I have two scenarios. `1.When a new user login using the Google account, I need to create a new entry in my application user table and manage what ever the records he created. 2. How to identify if the existing user logs in using Google Account.`

Answer (score 0):

Ages ago I've created small ASP. NET MVC and if I remember correctly you can find the solution described [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find your answer in this Google+ document regarding adding Google+ authentication to existing Facebook implementations:

[Adding Google+ to your Facebook Integration: Storing authorization](https://developers.google.com/+/best-practices/facebook#storing_authorization)

It talks about migrating from a single `User` table to a `User` and `Identity` table.

You could implement something like this in two ways:

1. Keep the username/password/email fields on the `User` table, and attach a Google authentication provider in the `Identity` table only when necessary.
2. Include username and password fields on the `Identity` table which are checked if the `provider` is `"local"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) for that.

This is a "library that adds support for your site visitors to login with their OpenIDs by just dropping an ASP.NET control onto your page. It's that easy. An AJAX-style OpenID Selector control is also included for a slick, streamlined user experience."

[This post](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/implementing-google-account) explains how to work with it for Google account.